How to layout child elements so they will not move when parent element resizes or moves?
I have a parent div and place three svg ellipses and a image inside it. They need to have a certain position on top of the div. This position needs to be always the same no matter where the div moves or if it shrinks/grows (i want to execute an event when a certain position on the image gets clicked).
So far i was able to make the child elements shrink/grow with the parent div. They have a stable position inside the div, as long as top and left attribute is zero. As this is not possible, i am not sure how to accomplish it.
export const Example = () => {
  const hello1 = () => {
    // Add your event handling logic here
    window.alert("Hello 1!");
  };
  const hello2 = () => {
    // Add your event handling logic here
    window.alert("Hello 2!");
  };

  const hello3 = () => {
    // Add your event handling logic here
    window.alert("Hello 3!");
  };

return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", position: "relative" }}>
        <img src={VillageBack} alt="Village Back" style={{ flex: 1, objectFit: "contain" }} />
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style={{ position: "absolute", top: -250, left: 0 }} >
          <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="10" ry="15" fill="blue" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={hello1} />
        </svg>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: -190 }} >
          <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="10" ry="15" fill="blue" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={hello2} />
        </svg>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style={{ position: "absolute", top: -140, left: 280 }} >
          <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="10" ry="15" fill="blue" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={hello3} />
        </svg>
     
    </div>
  );
};

I am using it in react, but should be applicable for plain js as well.
My second problem is, that only the lowest svg is clickable. All others do not get recongized. Why? They are not overlapping
GOOD, because not shrinked

BAD, because shrunk


Are the ellipses supposed to shrink/grow with the image? Frankly though this sounds like something for an Image Map

But it sounds like you want something like this- https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYELEo Note that the positions are defined by percentage as are the objects on the image.

Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot
